# how to get the result of active record insert in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I'm using active record in CodeIgniter.
And I can insert data into database successfully.
But how to get the result of insert sql when fail?
Now it return a html say about the sql error.
I don't want this html content.

EDIT

```
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'date' => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

Simple code. But when the 'name' column has unique property. And I'm inserting a duplicate value to it. It return html content of sql error.

I just want it to return the error code and not output the html content.

Comment: What code have you written so far? What do you want to accomplish: do you want to get a message that the query was executed, do you want to return the values you just entered in the database or do you want to get rid of an SQL error?

Comment: Well that's the model, nothing wrong with that. What does your controller and view look like?

Comment: Nice poem :)     (I needed 3 more chars to go...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To not get the DB error message make sure that you have `$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE` in the file `/application/config/database.php`.

Then after you've preformed your (attempted) insert you can run:

`$num_inserts = $this->db->affected_rows();`

If the result is 0, your insert failed and you can present an error message of your own choosing.

Comment: I don't know how it was before, but $this->db->affected_rows() actually returns -1 on failure (after an insert). It returns 0 if no rows has been updated after an update query.

Answer (score 2):

Use these functions

```
$errNo   = $this->db->_error_number();
$errMess = $this->db->_error_message();
```

They will help

Comment: You're missing a ';' in the end of the first line.